# Rails form with nested attributes saving twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

Integrating rails form with nested forms, everything is working fine but the issue that is that records are saving multiple times.

app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :badges, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :badges, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if:  proc { |attributes| attributes['badge_type'] == "0" }
```

app/models/badge.rb

```
belongs_to :user_id
```

app/controllers/user_controller.rb

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.badges.build
end

def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   @user.save!
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,badges_attributes: [:id, :badge_type,:_destroy])
end
```

app/views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :badges do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.check_box :badge_type %>
    <label>Admin</label>
<% end %>
```

But it is saving records two times. How to fix that?

Comment: Is it saving duplicate records for both the user and the badge? Or one user but duplicate badges?

Comment: for the badges only

Comment: Can you give use an example of the parameters that are sent when you submit the form?

Answer (score -1):

When creating a new `User`, you just have to pass the `:badges` attributes as part of the `user_params`

#### user_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :phone, :email, attributes_for_badges: %i[id badge_type _destroy])
end
```

Comment: I update my question and using permit params also but its still creating duplicate records

Comment: Try calling User.new(user_params) then save it. No need to go for @user.badges.build.

Comment: Again, remove the `@user.badges.build` and only use my code. The endpoint should be according to your `:new` method. I have used `:create` because I'm following REST. For you, the code should be inside your `:new` method

Comment: if we remove @user.badges.build in new action then how it will show in form..please write your new action